# How can I convert Pine-script to Python? (QQE signal)

Tags: python, pine-script, tradingview-api

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CiBoH.png)

`Pine-script code`

```
//@version=4
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © colinmck

study("QQE signals", overlay=true)

RSI_Period = input(14, title='RSI Length')
SF = input(5, title='RSI Smoothing')
QQE = input(4.238, title='Fast QQE Factor')
ThreshHold = input(10, title="Thresh-hold")

src = close
Wilders_Period = RSI_Period * 2 - 1

Rsi = rsi(src, RSI_Period)
RsiMa = ema(Rsi, SF)
AtrRsi = abs(RsiMa[1] - RsiMa)
MaAtrRsi = ema(AtrRsi, Wilders_Period)
dar = ema(MaAtrRsi, Wilders_Period) * QQE

longband = 0.0
shortband = 0.0
trend = 0

DeltaFastAtrRsi = dar
RSIndex = RsiMa
newshortband = RSIndex + DeltaFastAtrRsi
newlongband = RSIndex - DeltaFastAtrRsi
longband := RSIndex[1] > longband[1] and RSIndex > longband[1] ? max(longband[1], newlongband) : newlongband
shortband := RSIndex[1] < shortband[1] and RSIndex < shortband[1] ? min(shortband[1], newshortband) : newshortband
cross_1 = cross(longband[1], RSIndex)
trend := cross(RSIndex, shortband[1]) ? 1 : cross_1 ? -1 : nz(trend[1], 1)
FastAtrRsiTL = trend == 1 ? longband : shortband

// Find all the QQE Crosses

QQExlong = 0
QQExlong := nz(QQExlong[1])
QQExshort = 0
QQExshort := nz(QQExshort[1])
QQExlong := FastAtrRsiTL < RSIndex ? QQExlong + 1 : 0
QQExshort := FastAtrRsiTL > RSIndex ? QQExshort + 1 : 0

//Conditions

qqeLong = QQExlong == 1 ? FastAtrRsiTL[1] - 50 : na
qqeShort = QQExshort == 1 ? FastAtrRsiTL[1] - 50 : na

// Plotting

plotshape(qqeLong, title="QQE long", text="Long", textcolor=color.white, style=shape.labelup, location=location.belowbar, color=color.green, transp=0, size=size.tiny)
plotshape(qqeShort, title="QQE short", text="Short", textcolor=color.white, style=shape.labeldown, location=location.abovebar, color=color.red, transp=0, size=size.tiny)

// Alerts

alertcondition(qqeLong, title="Long", message="Long")
alertcondition(qqeShort, title="Short", message="Short")
```

`python code`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import talib as ta
import math
import ccxt

RSI_Period = 6
Wilders_Period = RSI_Period * 2 - 1
SF = 5
QQE = 3
ThresHold = 3

data = client.klines(symbol='BTCUSDT', interval='3m', limit=1000) ## binance API data

df = pd.DataFrame(data)# DATA

Rsi = ta.RSI(df['close'], RSI_Period) ## RSI
RsiMa = ta.EMA(Rsi, SF) ## EMA
AtrRsi = abs(RsiMa[-1] - RsiMa)

MaAtrRsi = ta.EMA(AtrRsi, Wilders_Period) ## EMA
dar = ta.EMA(MaAtrRsi, Wilders_Period) * QQE
```

It is incomplete.

I'm not trying to implement a graph, I simply want to run longs and shorts in real time.

I want to alert in python console whether it is long or short.

Is there a way to convert it to python?

I want to continuously fetch the data and determine when it is long and when it is short.

Answer (score 0):

#qqe  signal

```
    df["RSI_Period"]=ta.rsi (df['close'],14)
    SF = 5
    QQE = 4.238
    ThreshHold = input(10, title="Thresh-hold")

    src = df['close']
    Wilders_Period = df["RSI2"] * 2 - 1

    Rsi = rsi(src, RSI_Period)
    RsiMa = ta.ema(Rsi, SF)
    AtrRsi = abs(RsiMa[1] - RsiMa)
    MaAtrRsi = ta.ema(AtrRsi, Wilders_Period)
    dar = ema(MaAtrRsi, Wilders_Period) * QQE

    longband = 0.0
    shortband = 0.0
    trend = 0

    DeltaFastAtrRsi = dar
    RSIndex = RsiMa
    newshortband = RSIndex + DeltaFastAtrRsi
    newlongband = RSIndex - DeltaFastAtrRsi
    if longband == RSIndex[-1] > longband[-1] and RSIndex > longband[-1] ? max(longband[-1], newlongband) : newlongband
    shortband == RSIndex[-1] < shortband[-1] and RSIndex < shortband[-1] ? min(shortband[-1], newshortband) : newshortband
    cross_1 = cross(longband[1], RSIndex)
    trend == cross(RSIndex, shortband[1]) ? 1 : cross_1 ? -1 : nz(trend[1], 1)
    FastAtrRsiTL = trend == 1 ? longband : shortband

    # Find all the QQE Crosses

    QQExlong = 0
    QQExlong == nz(QQExlong[-1])
    QQExshort = 0
    QQExshort == nz(QQExshort[-1])
    QQExlong == FastAtrRsiTL < RSIndex ? QQExlong + 1 : 0
    QQExshort == FastAtrRsiTL > RSIndex ? QQExshort + 1 : 0

    #Conditions

    qqeLong = QQExlong == 1 ? FastAtrRsiTL[-1] - 50 : na
    qqeShort = QQExshort == 1 ? FastAtrRsiTL[-1] - 50 : na
```

? I couldn't find what to use instead.